# Gunicorn TypeError __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given with Flask application Factory

Tags: flask, gunicorn, python-3.9

I have been searching through for days now trying to find an answer to why this is happing. I have a Flask application using the application factory method. Everything runs fine via the Flask development server, so now I'm trying to deploy with Gunicorn as recommended. I have done this before and it has seemed to work, but that wasn't using the application factory method of instantiating my app. So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

I have tried several of the suggestions I have found of different ways to run the `gunicorn` command but nothing seems to work. The workers start up just fine, but as soon as I perform a request via google to any one of my endpoints (mostly the simple GET request to render the initial page) I get the following traceback that occurs.

```py
[2021-04-26 14:37:34 -0500] [25609] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25609)
[2021-04-26 14:37:34 -0500] [25608] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-04-26 14:37:34 -0500] [25608] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
(learn_flask_sqlalchemy) [aspea002@ilscha03-ioad-01 learn_flask_sqlalchemy]$ ls
app.py  config.py  migrations  __pycache__  README.md  requirements.txt  student_directory  wsgi.py
(learn_flask_sqlalchemy) [aspea002@ilscha03-ioad-01 learn_flask_sqlalchemy]$ gunicorn "student_directory:create_app()"
[2021-04-26 14:38:00 -0500] [25796] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-04-26 14:38:00 -0500] [25796] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (25796)
[2021-04-26 14:38:00 -0500] [25796] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-04-26 14:38:00 -0500] [25797] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25797
/home/aspea002/miniconda3/envs/learn_flask_sqlalchemy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
/home/aspea002/miniconda3/envs/learn_flask_sqlalchemy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
[2021-04-26 14:38:06 -0500] [25797] [ERROR] Error handling request /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aspea002/miniconda3/envs/learn_flask_sqlalchemy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/aspea002/miniconda3/envs/learn_flask_sqlalchemy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 179, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
[2021-04-26 14:38:07 -0500] [25797] [ERROR] Error handling request /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aspea002/miniconda3/envs/learn_flask_sqlalchemy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/aspea002/miniconda3/envs/learn_flask_sqlalchemy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 179, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

`__init__.py` file that you see has the following contents:

```py
import os
import logging
import sys

from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_script import Manager, Server
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
# from student_directory import jobs
from student_directory.students.models import db


def create_app():
    student_app = Flask(__name__)
    student_app.config.from_object(os.environ.get('app_env'))
    db.init_app(student_app)
    manager = Manager(student_app)
    migrate = Migrate(student_app, db)
    manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
    # scheduler = APScheduler()
    # scheduler.init_app(student_app)
    # scheduler.start()
    student_api = Api(student_app)
    if 'runserver' in sys.argv:
        manager.add_command('runserver', Server(use_debugger=student_app.config.get('DEBUG'),
                                                threaded=student_app.config.get('THREADED'), port=student_app.config.get('PORT'),
                                                host=student_app.config.get('HOST'),
                                                use_reloader=student_app.config.get('USE_RELOADER')))
    with student_app.app_context():
        from . import routes

    return manager
```

I have tried to do some of the suggestion that you can call the `create_app()` method directly:

```
gunicorn -w 2 "student_directory:create_app()"
```

I have also tried the `wsgi.py` file approach as well with the contents of that file being:

```py
from student_directory import create_app

student_app = create_app()
```

With gunicorn command `gunicorn -w 2 wsgi:student_app`.

But no matter what I do every request keeps hitting this exception in the `sync.py` file of `gunicorn` and I'm not sure why.

Any advice would be great cause at this point I'm assuming it has something with what I am doing or I need to be doing differently with the latest version of `gunicorn`. I have used it previously like a said about a year or so ago and it worked fine so I'm not sure what has changed so drastically according to the Gunicorn release notes update.